# Why am I getting this ImportError? cannot import name 'setting' from 'social_django.utils

Tags: python, django

```
ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. 

ImportError: cannot import name 'setting' from 'social_django.utils' (/Users/Scott/Desktop/myvirtualenv/crazy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_django/utils.py).
```

Here are my settings.py followed by my urls.py files.  If anymore information is needed to diagnose this issue please let me know.

Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'blank'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Crazyapp',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'social_django',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Crazy.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Crazy.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
   'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Facebook configuration
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'blank'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'blank'

# Define SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE to get extra permissions from Facebook.
# Email is not sent by default, to get it, you must request the email permission.
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id, name, email'
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',  # django-oauth-toolkit < 1.0.0
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',  # django-oauth-toolkit >= 1.0.0
    ),
}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from Crazyapp import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from social_django.utils import psa

from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),

    # Restaurant
    url(r'^restaurant/sign-in/$', auth_views.LoginView,
        {'template_name': 'restaurant/sign_in.html'},
        name = 'restaurant-sign-in'),
    url(r'^restaurant/sign-out', auth_views.LogoutView,
        {'next_page': '/'},
        name = 'restaurant-sign-out'),
    url(r'^restaurant/sign-up', views.restaurant_sign_up,
        name = 'restaurant-sign-up'),
    url(r'^restaurant/$', views.restaurant_home, name = 'restaurant_home'),

    # Sign In/ Sign Up/ Sign Out
    url(r'^api/social/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls')),
    # /convert-token (sign in/ sign up)
    # /revoke-token (sign out)
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login')
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout')

    path('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
```

Comment: you probably don't want to post your SECRET_KEY and Facebook credentials here.  (You should now change those FB credentials.)

Comment: Also for future practice it would probably be beneficial to pull these secrets in through environment variables rather than having them hard-coded in.

Comment: absolutely, I took them out but will also be changing them before I go into production with the app.  I do appreciate the heads up though.  I see an opening in my local market for this type of service but I do not have the capital to pay for this app to be developed up front.  Clearly I am not a developer or a coder so I greatly appreciate this website.  The plan is to use my app to make the service available to the town I reside and use profits to have a professional development company update my app.